# node/mocha http POST binary file (via body, not form) ends in parse Error

Tags: node.js, image, http, binary, mocha.js

This is my code.

The Docs of Node.js say I can post a buffer. But I am always getting a parse error. My API is working, but the test not.

You may know, what I am doing wrong? Thanks for help!

```
it('POST - /api/user-image', function (done) {

var file_path_rel = '/user-images/testimage.jpg';
var file_path = path.join(__dirname + file_path_rel);

fs.readFile(file_path, function (err, image) {

  if (err) done(err);

  var buffer = new Buffer(image, "binary");

  var options = {
    host: config.host,
    port: config.port,
    path: '/api/user-image',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
      "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
      "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });

  req.write(buffer);
  req.end();
});
```

This is the error. Other Tests (OAuth) are working fine via http.

```
Error: Parse Error
at Error (native)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the image variable to Buffer because its already a buffer (you don't specify the encoding and therefore readFile callback data argument is a buffer). Read [readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) documentation for more information.

The error you are seeing is not related with the content you are sending to the server but with the content the server is sending you back. Notice that the error is happening once the client try to parse the response send by the server. May be the server is setting Content-Length header to a wrong value? This guys where having the same error than you on this [issue](https://github.com/koajs/send/issues/34).

Comment: Thank you for this tip! But it is still not changing my problem. I am still getting this error message.

Comment: I thought so too, but requests with POSTMAN are working fine. I've figured out more the problem by making a node module out of it and not using mocha. The chunk I get, is a buffer too ... i don't know why ...